# Ключевое слово restrict внутри квадратных скобок

Tags: c

Просматривая стандарт *POSIX* наткнулся
на [такое объявление](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/lio_listio.html):

```
#include <aio.h>

int lio_listio(int mode, struct aiocb *restrict const list[restrict],
       int nent, struct sigevent *restrict sig);
```

(Выделение добавлено.) Я понимаю, что значит ключевое
слово `restrict` в общем случае, но что оно
означает здесь?

Comment: Плюсик как минимум за мастерское форматирование. :)

Comment: Тут оно (то что в скобках) означает, что все блоки ***aiocb*** (в функцию передается массив адресов этих блоков) должны быть разными.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашел. [Черновик C11](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), 6.7.6.3/7:

> A declaration of a parameter as ‘‘array of `type`’’ shall be adjusted to ‘‘qualified pointer to `type`’’,  where  the  `type`  qualifiers  (if  any)  are  those  specified  within  the `[` and `]` of  the array  type  derivation.

Получается, `void foo(int x[restrict]);` эквивалентно `void foo(int *restrict x);`. Это можно проверить, написав два объявления рядом и убедившись в отсутствии ругани компилятора на разные типы.

Comment: То есть, это массив на *restrict*-указатели, который и сам сводится к *restrict*-указателю?

Comment: @Ainar-G *"То есть, это массив на restrict-указатели"* Не очень понял. По идее, это вообще невалидное объявление массива (в том смысле что это работает только в параметрах функций).

Comment: Я имею в виду то, что написано [вот тут](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/restrict) в последнем параграфе перед секцией *Notes*.  «*It qualifies the pointer type to which the array type is transformed*».

Answer (score 0):

такое сделали чтобы можно было указать и размер массива и что указатель на массив индивидуальный. `void f(int a[restrict 9]);` При декларации как указатель `void f(int * restrict a);` количество не проставишь.

В вашем случае `[restrict]` в квадратных скобках означает всего-лишь, что список `list` - это массив, а не указатель на один элемент.